# Add a second line in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and I am playing around with it.

```
PS C:\PowerShell> New-Item C:\PowerShell\test.ps1 -type file -force -value "Ping jay"
```

I want to add Ping google.com below ping jay
When I run the script it pings jay which is a pc here then after it completes I want it to ping google.com

Comment: Got it.  New-Item C:\PowerShell\test.ps1 -type file -force -value "ping google.com"

Comment: Add-Content C:\PowerShell\test.ps1 "`nPing jay"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"ping google.com" | add-content C:\PowerShell\test.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

the Semicolon is the line seperator in powershell:

`New-Item C:\PowerShell\test.ps1 -type file -force -value "Ping jay ; Ping google.com"`